# C - Sum of Array using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sum

I've tried many different variants of both of the ways, and cannot get it to sum the array. It's passed into the function as a pointer and need to calc the mean and return.

```
unsigned char calcMean(unsigned char *buffer, int height, int width)
{    
   unsigned char mean, sum=0;
   counter i, k;
   int size;

   size = width*height;

   mean = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       sum += buffer[i];
   }

   /*

   for(k=0;k<(width*height);k++)
   {
     mean = mean + *Buffer;
     frameBuffer++;
        printf("%d\n", mean);
   }        
   */   

    return sum;

 }
```

Comment: `sum` may be out of range of `unsigned char` type. Consider declaring is as a variable of larger data type like `int`.

Comment: What output do you get?  What values are in `buffer[i]` when you run it under a debugger?

Comment: How is buffer filled? What happens when you run this code? Why are you trying to sum chars instead of integers? Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: @sgar91 it has to be that type, the output for mean is zero, same for sum

Comment: sorry guys for not clearly defining the question, i'm not sure how to sum the elements of an array that this pointer is pointing to

Comment: Your code looks mostly fine for summing the elements. As @sgar91 pointed out, the variable you're storing your `sum` into is a `unsigned char`, which means it will overflow unless your sum is small (255 or smaller)... so change its type to something larger to avoid this.

Comment: The sum looks ok to me... Are you sure you're allocating the memory for `buffer`?

Comment: @sgar91 and Steve thanks guys it was that i'd neglected the size of the sum variable.

Answer (score 2):

`mean` can be a char, since you would divide by `size` to calculate it. But the `sum` itself can be as high as `size` * 255 (8bits of `unsigned char`).
`width * height` can overflow too.

To be at the safe side (on 32 or 64bit machines), consider this:

16bit * 16bit integer would require a 32bit integer (for the dimension).
An unsigned char array with a size up to 4294967295 would then require 64bits for the sum.

So, if possible, use explicit integer sizes (C99):

```
uint8_t calcMean(uint8_t *buffer, uint16_t height, uint16_t width)
{    
   uint64_t sum=0;
   size_t i;
   size_t size;//size_t is large enough to store a pointer,
               //so it would have 32 or 64bits on corresponding platforms
               //(see uintptr_t, etc.)

   size = ((size_t)width)*((size_t)height);

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       sum += buffer[i];
   }

   return sum / size;
}
```

Comment: Or just use `size_t` everywhere.

Comment: You're right, I should've mentioned `size_t`. When built in 64bit mode, `size_t` would exceed those requirements, but that wouldn't make much of a difference. However, one could still use `uint16_t` for `width` and `height`, just for the sake of self explaining code.

Answer (score 0):

To guard yourself from buffer overflow for the `buffer[]` array, assuming you have array defined and initialized with values, pass size of array along with pointer to array's first element rather than the method you have currently to `calcMean()`.

Call to `calcMean()` shall be:

```
uint8_t array_name[3]={1,2,3}; /* Array size and values assumed */
...
calcMean(array_name, sizeof(array_name))
```

`calcMean()` definition shall be :

```
uint8_t calcMean(uint8_t *buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
    uint64_t sum=0;
    size_t i;

    for(i = 0; i < buffer_size; i++)
    {
        sum += buffer[i];
    }
    ..../*Do whatever you want if at all needed */

    return (sum / size);
}
```